# Как сделать так чтобы админ интернет магазина мог добавить несколько картинок к товару? Пишу на Express, Node js, React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

Код контроллера

```
        const {img} = req.files
        let fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg"
        img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', {fileName}))
```

Компонент добавления товара

```
         const [file, setFile] = useState(null)

         const selectFile = e => {
         setFile(e.target.files[0])}

         formData.append('img', file)


         <Form.Control
          className="mt-3"
          type="file"
          onChange={selectFile}
          />
```

Comment: Ну для начала вам бы сохранять не один элемент из files, а весь массив. Потом выполнить `formData.append` столько раз, сколько у вас файлов.